# wso2 msf4j microservice is timeout

Tags: wso2, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I am using wso2 msf4j to implement micro services in my project. I have the following issue,
    Microservice is sometimes timeout.
    Microservice is sometimes turned off.

I didn’t see anything in logging despite the logging mode is debug, and I logged many places in my code.  I don’t have any starting points to debug and address those issues. 
Could anyone help me to address those issues.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any DB operations in ur microservice? I've never encountered such a scenario. You can put a debug point in ur service and check if the service gets hit

Comment: Microservice has DB operations. But after putting a debug point in service(even on first line of handler), I couldn't see that log. Problem happens somewhere on framework.

Comment: What is the msf4j version that you are trying? If you have the msf4j source could you put a debug point in the MSF4JMessageProcessor.receive() method and check if the MSF4J receive the message?

Comment: Can you invoke the MSF4J hello service without any issue?

Comment: Thank you all. I have found problem. 
That was because of using okhttp, and I made incorrect configuration, so each time of making okhttp request, system creates new okhttp pool of connections. That makes amount of threads in system significantly bigger (to 1000 of threads). 
After that each time msf4j get new request, I think It can't create new thread to handle new request, request become timeout, and I can't see any log in handling.

Comment: So when doing http calls from your service you are creating separate threads?